# Cloning a fixture in love2d

Tags: clone, physics, love2d

So, I'm trying to make a platformer game and the "platforms" are made of multiple 16x16 pixel tiles.

I simply have no idea how to do this, although I thought of using the clone() function to clone the original fixture and put it slightly to the right and repeating this until there is a platform.

Not sure how to phrase this question, so write in the comments what is unclear and i'll do my best to explain it(sorry).

this is the full code that I have so far:

```
tile = {}
slime = {}
obj = {}    
scale = 8

function love.load()
    love.graphics.setDefaultFilter( "nearest" )

    slime.f1 = love.graphics.newImage("slime_f1.png")
    slime.f2 = love.graphics.newImage("slime_f2.png")
    tile.dirt = love.graphics.newImage("tile.png")

    love.physics.setMeter(64)
    world = love.physics.newWorld(0, 9.81 * 64, true)

    obj.player = {}
    obj.player.body = love.physics.newBody(world, 100, 0, "dynamic")
    obj.player.shape = love.physics.newCircleShape(slime.f1:getWidth() / 2 * scale)
    obj.player.fixture = love.physics.newFixture(obj.player.body, obj.player.shape)

    obj.tile = {}
    obj.tile.body = love.physics.newBody(world, 100, 500, "kinematic")
    obj.tile.shape = love.physics.newRectangleShape(tile.dirt:getWidth() * scale, tile.dirt:getHeight() * scale)
    obj.tile.fixture = love.physics.newFixture(obj.tile.body, obj.tile.shape)

end

function love.draw()
    love.graphics.draw(slime.f1, obj.player.body:getX(), obj.player.body:getY(), 0, scale, scale, slime.f1:getWidth()/2, slime.f1:getHeight()/2)
    love.graphics.draw(tile.dirt, obj.tile.body:getX(), obj.tile.body:getY(), 0, scale, scale, tile.dirt:getWidth()/2, tile.dirt:getHeight()/2)
end

function love.update(dt)
    world:update(dt)
    if (love.keyboard.isDown("escape")) then
        love.event.quit()
    end
    if (love.keyboard.isDown("space")) then
        obj.player.body:setLinearVelocity(0, -500)
    end
end
```

Comment: If I'm understanding, you're trying to repeat the same 16x16 tile to create larger structures in the game?

Comment: yup, preety much it